# How Do I Override GET in Django Detailview?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a FORMVIEW that is redirecting to a DETAILVIEW and that is working perfectly.  The issue I'm having is when I try to combine Pagination with DetailView.  When I try to leverage the pagination, the GET is essentially redirecting me to the FORMVIEW.  I get why it's doing this...I'm telling it to.  What I'm trying to work out is how I can put in some logic in my overridden GET.  I tried to do a self.GET_OBJECT.pk...to see if I could determine if I'm on the current page and not the FORMVIEW but that didn't work...

Here's my DetailView....

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SuggestionByNameDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    attachments = SuggestionFiles.objects.filter(suggestion=self.object.pk).all()
    comment_form = SuggestionCommentForm()
    response_form = SuggestionCommentReplyForm()
    activities= self.get_related_activities()
    context['suggestion_comments'] = activities
    context['page_obj'] = activities
    context['attachments'] = attachments
    context['comment_form'] = comment_form
    context['response_form'] = response_form
    return context

def get_related_activities(self):
    queryset = self.object.suggestion_comments.all()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset,5) #paginate_by
    page = self.request.GET.get('page')
    activities = paginator.get_page(page)
    return activities

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return get_object_or_404(Suggestion, id=self.request.GET.get("dropdown"))

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    dropdown=self.request.GET.get("dropdown")

    if dropdown is not None:
        if Suggestion.objects.filter(Q(id=self.request.GET.get("dropdown"))).distinct():
            self.object = self.get_object()
            context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            return self.render_to_response(context)
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, 'Suggestion is required.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Suggestions:suggestion_by_name'))
```

As mentioned I did try to do something like...if DROPDOWN is NONE and pk = self.get_object().pk...to essentially try and determine if I can just bypass the DROPDOWN logic in GET...but the PK is always present...I also tried to do something like self.request.GET.get('pk') but that didn't work either.

When I click to do the pagination I get redirected back to the FORMVIEW.  I'm trying to avoid that once I'm on the DETAILVIEW.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts on what I can do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

So....after a couple of hours....turns out....GET may be an issue...but here's a way around it.....The "canned" django code...for pagination looks something like this...

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="button77">Next</a>
```

In my case...I simply needed to get more specific with my URL...so it now looks more like....

```
<a href="/LevelSet/Suggestions/suggestion_by_name_detail/26a12149-62bf-48fe-8e7e-3a71231f7229/?dropdown={{dropdown}}&page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="button77">Next</a>
```

Case closed.  This one anyway.  :).